# function's parameters without passing it, c programming

Tags: c, function, parameters

is there a way to obtain function's parameters, inside this function, without passing it. Like the **func** providing the function name. i'd like to obtain just name of parameters, not type.

search with google, found functions for line, function name and file name but nothing about parameters

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27642694/13285779) may help, however I don't think you can do it in a general concise manner.

Comment: I don't see why this would be useful. You need to use the argument names to access their values, so why not just do the same, but in text? The maintenance issue is no different.

Comment: X-Y problem IMO

Comment: my goal is to call a function, let call it disp(), in any kind of function with the purpose to display the name of the function and all it parameter's names and values without the need to give this parameters to disp(); with reflexivity of POO it can be achive easyly so i wondered if it's possible in C

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, automated logging would address the problem of devs too lazy to spend the extra 0.002% of time writing the few extra lines of code needed to reliably log things. (Amazingly, the same devs who can't figure out why they always have to spend weeks or months figuring out why their code occasionally doesn't work...)

Comment: C does not have any kind of [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming) or [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection).

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not provide any facility for this.